# Code coverage for test framework written in Node and application is in Java

Tags: java, node.js, automation, code-coverage, jacoco

I have written my test framework which is a node service and the application is written in Java. I want to understand how to get code coverage? I have tried to use Jacoco but it did not generate any coverage details. Is there any dependency for node projects for jacoco that I should use ? Or is there any other way of generating code coverage for this type of scenario ?

I have added dependencies to pom.xml as here

```
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                    <outputDirectory>/target/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: "generating" code coverage? you mean checking which code is covered?

Comment: Yes . I want to get the lines which are covered in the java application

Comment: Updated the description and tried to run it using mvn jacoco:report